# Can not draw a circle on top of rectangle in html5

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I am using html5 and I want to draw a circle on top of a rectangle so I used the following html code:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" style="z-index: 1;width:70%;height: 70%;float: left;">

<canvas id="c1" style="z-index: 2;width:10%;height: 10%;float: left;"></canvas>
```

and following js code:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.rect(10,10,$("#myCanvas").height(),$("#myCanvas").width());
  ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();


  var canvas = document.getElementById('c1');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var centerX = $("#myCanvas").height()/ 2;
  var centerY = $("#myCanvas").width() / 2;
  var radius = 70;

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  context.fillStyle = 'green';
  context.fill();
  context.lineWidth = 5;
  context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
  context.stroke();

  });
```

and here is the jfiddle link:

[jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7FuL9/)

Now the problem is that the circle is not shown and I do not know what is the problem!!!
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you need two canvases?  I would do it on one.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.rect(10,10,$("#myCanvas").height(),$("#myCanvas").width());
    ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();

    var centerX = $("#myCanvas").height()/ 2;
    var centerY = $("#myCanvas").width() / 2;
    var radius = 70;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#003300';
    ctx.stroke();

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7FuL9/2/

Comment: Just a quick question when I use these two lines   var centerX = $("#myCanvas").height()/ 2;var centerY = $("#myCanvas").width() / 2;    I expect the circle in the center of mycanvas but as you can see it is not in the center. Can tell me why?

Comment: @HamedMinaee Try setting the width and height attributes of the canvas tag to match the width and height you set in the style tag. That should fix your problem. Here's another JSBin with the circle in the center: http://jsbin.com/kihikibo/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Ya, that's right, you need inner width of the canvas and adjusted center x, y for your radius.  Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7FuL9/5/

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need two canvas tags to do this? This can be done with just one canvas. Here is a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/wigiqode/1/edit?html,js,output) that draws a circle on top of a rectangle.